# Jason encode binary to UUID in Elixir

Tags: elixir, uuid, elixir-jason

I'm trying to think of a clean way to override the [Jason](https://hex.pm/packages/jason)[Encoder](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.Encoder.html) for binary that would allow me to pull out UUIDs from binary. Here is what I would like to do in theory:

```elixir
defimpl Jason.Encoder, for: BitString do
  def encode(binary, opts) when is_binary(binary) do
    with false <- String.valid?(binary),
    {:ok, uid} <- Ecto.UUID.cast(binary) do
      uid
    else
    _ -> Jason.Encode.string(binary, opts)
    end
  end

  def encode(bitstring, _opts) do
    raise Protocol.UndefinedError,
      protocol: @protocol,
      value: bitstring,
      description: "cannot encode a bitstring to JSON"
  end
end
```

I'm thinking along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164792/elixir-jason-encode-struct-with-tuple#answer-56167605) stackoverflow example, except I think the issue here is that native types like BitString can not be overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to globally override the protocol for `BitString`, you can wrap a UUID in its own struct, and implement the `Jason.Encoder` protocol for that struct:

```elixir
defmodule JsonUUID do
  defstruct [:uuid]

  defimpl Jason.Encoder do
    def encode(%JsonUUID{uuid: uuid}, opts) when is_binary(uuid) do
      uuid
      |> Ecto.UUID.cast!()
      |> Jason.Encode.string(opts)
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```elixir
Jason.encode!(%JsonUUID{uuid: Ecto.UUID.bingenerate()})
=> "\"8cbf3df9-8408-4ce3-ac44-980a0f7dc19b\""
```